# Can external objects access custom objects in the same org?

Tags: externalobjects

The [External Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_external_objects.htm) documentation describes a cross-org adapter that:

> Uses the Lightning Platform REST API to access data that’s stored in
>   other Salesforce orgs.

Can this (or some other technique) be used to adapt local custom objects?

(Wondering here about External Object definitions that are related to each other pulling in local custom object data rather than external data. Then logic built around the External Object field name of say `ExtObj__x.Abc__x` could actually be working against the local custom object field of say `CusObj__c.Xyz__c`. The External Object is as acting as an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).)

Comment: Trying to understand here, what is the use case here for an external object to be able to access data from a custom object in the same org? For *what* the external object here acts as an *adapter*?

Comment: @JayantDas The use case is that vendor A creates external objects with UI and logic and other vendors B, C, D etc plug their custom objects into that vendor A system.